# How to sort an array from linear distribution to normal distribution in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting

Think there is an original array:

```
$array[] = array('name' => 'a', 'code'=>1); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'b', 'code'=>2); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'c', 'code'=>3); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'd', 'code'=>4); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'e', 'code'=>5); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'f', 'code'=>6); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'g', 'code'=>7); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'h', 'code'=>8); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'i', 'code'=>9);
```

it's linear sort by `code`, and how can sort it as normal distribution by `code` like this:

```
$array[] = array('name' => 'a', 'code'=>1); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'c', 'code'=>3); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'e', 'code'=>5); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'g', 'code'=>7); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'i', 'code'=>9); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'h', 'code'=>8); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'f', 'code'=>6); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'd', 'code'=>4); 
$array[] = array('name' => 'b', 'code'=>2);
```

Maybe `usort` could help?

---

**UPDATE**

When I say `Normal Distribution`, I mean like the image below, the biggest number is in the middle:

[image: normal distribution]

And does there be some **`COMMON`** method can do it? Maybe this time it's *'normal distribution'* and next time I want another rule for sorting? 
Does there be some way like `usort` to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

This will do it. The below code will split the array into two new arrays. Anything with an even number will be added to an array with the new element at the start. Anything with an odd number will be added to the end of the other new array. Then you simply merge them.

```
$array = [];

$array[] = array('name' => 'a', 'code'=>1);
$array[] = array('name' => 'b', 'code'=>2);
$array[] = array('name' => 'c', 'code'=>3);
$array[] = array('name' => 'd', 'code'=>4);
$array[] = array('name' => 'e', 'code'=>5);
$array[] = array('name' => 'f', 'code'=>6);
$array[] = array('name' => 'g', 'code'=>7);
$array[] = array('name' => 'h', 'code'=>8);
$array[] = array('name' => 'i', 'code'=>9);



$array1 = [];
$array2 = [];


foreach ($array as $item) {
    $element = array_shift($array);

    if ($element['code'] % 2 == 0) {
        array_unshift($array1, $element);
    } else {
        $array2[] = $element;
    }
}

$array = array_merge($array2, $array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired array can be built in *O(n)* as follows:

```
$r = [];
for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  if ($i % 2) {
    $r []= $array[$i];
  } else {
    array_unshift($r, $array[$i]);
  }
}
```

The code iterates over the array items from the end. The items under odd indices (when `$i % 2` is non-zero) are added to the end of `$r`, and the items under even indices are added to the beginning of the array.

---

> it's linear sort by `code`, and how can sort it as normal distribution by `code`

The code above will produce the desired array, but the items *are not sorted in normal distribution* by `code`! In order to sort the items in *true* normal distribution by `code`, you would need to calculate the [probability density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of the normal distribution as follows:

```
/**
 * @param float $x the value
 * @param float $mean Mean or expectation of the distribution (median)
 * @param float $stddev Standard deviation
 * @return float Probability density of the normal distribution
 */
function dens_normal($x, $mean, $stddev) {
  $z = ($x - $mean) / $stddev;
  return (1 / ($stddev * sqrt(2.0 * pi()))) * exp(-0.5 * $z * $z);
}

// Calculate the mean code value
$mean = 0;
foreach ($array as $e) { $mean += $e['code']; }
$mean /= count($array);
echo "mean = $mean\n";

// Standard deviation for the code value
$stddev = 1;

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($mean, $stddev) {
  $da = dens_normal($a['code'], $mean, $stddev);
  $db = dens_normal($b['code'], $mean, $stddev);
  return $da == $db ? 0 : ($da < $db ? -1 : 1);
});


foreach ($array as $e) {
  printf("%s: %d\n", $e['name'], $e['code']);
}
```

*Output*

```
mean = 5
i: 9
a: 1
b: 2
h: 8
c: 3
g: 7
d: 4
f: 6
e: 5
```

The bigger the difference with the mean (`5`) value, the lower the array index. In other words, the array is sorted by the "degree of proximity" to the mean value (`5`) in descending order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my misunderstand for `normal distribution`, and looks like your answer is the best right now. But if there be some `common` method as described in the update?